# How to do group by multiple fields and sort on a different field, in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Lets say I have a query like

```
Select * from table
Group By field_1, field_2, field_3
Order By filed_7;
```

How to achieve the same functionality in elasticsearch.

I use **Composite Aggregations** to do **Group by multiple fields**. Is it possible to do the **sorting** part?